# Overlay video with a transparent Video using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I want to overlay two videos one over another using ffmpeg. I am able to do it, but i want to make the 2nd video transparent so that the base video can be visible.

Comment: Can you show the command you have so far?

Comment: ffmpeg -i vedeo1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[base];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,transpose=2,scale=400:-1[dependent];[base][dependent]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[out] -map [out] -y -movflags +faststart OutputVideo.mp4

I tried with using values tranparent and alpha channel but non of them seems to be working